# Download images from links and show in Android custom gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

I want to download images from bunch of .jpeg links and then show them in custom gallery.

I am able to download images, create bitmap and all...

To make entry of image in android galley, I use

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(obContext, new String[] { f.getAbsolutePath() }, null, null);
```

and To see only those particular images in my custom gallery I use folllowing code

```
Cursor imagecursor=managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        columns, 
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
            new String[] {"%myDesiredDirectory%"},  
            null);
```

But now

While scanning, it is creating thumbnails for newly downloaded images. These thumbnails also visible in gallery. So same pic is visible twice. Which is not desired.

Can anybody please help me to **avoid** creating thumbnails, and if its not avoidable, can we delete thumbnails also when we delete original files??

Thanks inn advance....

Answer (score 0):

one way to store your thumbnails would be to create custom object which will have thumbnail data, reference to original file, and some other data about thumbnail and then serialize the objects in a binary file. It'll be really fast to reload the thumbnails back from single binary file. Thumbnails are small so memory consumption shouldn't be an issue either.

if you don't want to create Thumbnails then just simply scale the images down to size of your `ImageView` and that way the images will appear nice and you don't have to create Thumbnails, but this operation can be time and memory expansive.

Comment: But I dont know what is their name and exact location and when they get created... Can you provide some code snippet to understand this thing of binary file creation, serialization etc? many thanks.